# issue getting the data at the time using ajax call(ajax and for)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, callback

I am getting data from ajax call and individuals working well.
But now I am going to get several data at the same time.

Code

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i ++){
  console.log(i);
  $.ajax({
  url: calculateURL(i),
  success: function(file_content){
     data[i] = file_content;
     console.log(i, file_content);
    }
  });
}
```

Result

```
1  
2  
3 "abc"  
3 "def"
```

Desired Result:

```
1  
2  
1 "abc"   
2 "def"
```

How can it be solved? 
Is there anyone who have experience in calling ajax in for loop?

Comment: Search for javascript closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ajaxLoad(i) {
 $.ajax({
    url: calculateURL(i),
    success: function(file_content){
        data[i] = file_content;
        console.log(i, file_content);
    }
 });
}
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i ++){
  ajaxLoad(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort